# Enqueue resources used percentage 108.65% too high for Database

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

want to know what is the default value of the parameter:enqueue_resources ?

What would be the way to act in case you report that it is full?

Answer (score 0):

Why do you care? `enqueue_resources` is obsolete since 10gR2, and you're on 11g.

As of 10g, this is what [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/server.101/b10755/initparams064.htm) says (excerpt):

> ENQUEUE_RESOURCES sets the number of resources that can be concurrently locked by the lock manager.
>
> The default value of ENQUEUE_RESOURCES is derived from the SESSIONS parameter and is usually adequate, as long as its value is greater than DML_LOCKS + 20. For three or fewer sessions, the default value is the number of database files + 20. For 4 to 10 sessions, the default value is the number of database files + ((SESSIONS - 3) * 5) + 20. For more than 10 sessions, it is the number of database files + ((SESSIONS - 10) * 2) + 55.

---

As of [SESSIONS](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14237/initparams191.htm#REFRN10197) parameter, Oracle suggests that

> you should always set this parameter explicitly to a value equivalent to your estimate of the maximum number of concurrent users, plus the number of background processes, plus approximately 10% for recursive sessions.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, let me check if it help us, Can you suggest what is SESSION and process parameter good value ?

Comment: You're welcome. I added some more info into my answer, regarding SESSIONS parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks you everyone, issue got solved after reboot and this was old setting which is deprecated already in lastest supported version.